# Spark - calculate max ocurrence per day-event

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following `RDD[String]`:

```
1:AAAAABAAAAABAAAAABAAABBB  
2:BBAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAA    
3:BBBBBBBBAAAABBAAAAAAAAAA
```

The first number is supposed to be `days` and the following characters are `events`.

I have to calculate the day where each event has the maximum occurrence.
The expected result for this dataset should be:

```
{ "A" -> Day2 , "B" -> Day3 }
```

(A has repeated 10 times in day2 and b 10 times in day3)

I am splitting the original dataset

```
val foo = rdd.map(_.split(":")).map(x => (x(0), x(1).split("")) )
```

What could be the best implementation for count and aggregation?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val rdd = sqlContext.sparkContext.makeRDD(Seq(
  "1:AAAAABAAAAABAAAAABAAABBB",
  "2:BBAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAA",
  "3:BBBBBBBBAAAABBAAAAAAAAAA"
))

val keys = Seq("A", "B")

val seqOfMaps: RDD[(String, Map[String, Int])] = rdd.map{str =>
  val split = str.split(":")
  (s"Day${split.head}", split(1).groupBy(a => a.toString).mapValues(_.length))
}

keys.map{key => {
  key -> seqOfMaps.mapValues(_.get(key).get).sortBy(a => -a._2).first._1
}}.toMap
```

Answer (score 0):

The processing that need to be done consist in transforming the data into a rdd that is easy to apply on functions like: find the maximum for a list
I will try to explain step by step

I've used dummy data for "A" and "B" chars.

The foo rdd is the first step it will give you RDD[(String, Array[String])]
Let's extract each char for the Array[String]

```
val res3 = foo.map{case (d,s)=> (d, s.toList.groupBy(c => c).map{case (x, xs) => (x, xs.size)}.toList)}

(1,List((A,18), (B,6)))
(2,List((A,20), (B,4)))
(3,List((A,14), (B,10)))
```

Next we will flatMap over values to expand our rdd by char

```
res3.flatMapValues(list => list)

(3,(A,14))
(3,(B,10))
(1,(A,18))
(2,(A,20))
(2,(B,4))
(1,(B,6))
```

Rearrange the rdd in order to look better

```
res5.map{case (d, (s, c)) => (s, c, d)}

(A,20,2)
(B,4,2)
(A,18,1)
(B,6,1)
(A,14,3)
(B,10,3)
```

Now we are groupy by char

```
res7.groupBy(_._1)

(A,CompactBuffer((A,18,1), (A,20,2), (A,14,3)))
(B,CompactBuffer((B,6,1), (B,4,2), (B,10,3)))
```

Finally we are taking the maxium count for each row

```
res9.map{case (s, list) => (s, list.maxBy(_._2))}

(B,(B,10,3))
(A,(A,20,2))
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are good, but I prefer such solution:

```
val data = Seq(
  "1:AAAAABAAAAABAAAAABAAABBB",
  "2:BBAAAAAAAAAABBAAAAAAAAAA",
  "3:BBBBBBBBAAAABBAAAAAAAAAA"
)
val initialRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(data)

// to tuples like (1,'A',18)
val charCountRDD = initialRDD.flatMap(s => {
  val parts = s.split(":")
  val charCount = parts(1).groupBy(i => i).mapValues(_.length)
  charCount.map(i => (parts(0), i._1, i._2))
})

// group by character, and take max value from grouped collection
val result = charCountRDD.groupBy(i => i._2).map(k => k._2.maxBy(z => z._3))
result.foreach(println(_))
```

Result is:

```
(3,B,10)
(2,A,20)
```